# Google Calendar Save Events to PHP Array

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to get all of events from a Google calendar and save them as a PHP array.  This is part of a bigger application that I don't have access to.

My attempt uses coreylib (http://github.com/collegeman/coreylib).  This library allows me to list all of the events, but not save them in an array.

```
<?php
require_once('coreylib.php');
$api = new clApi('https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/60vebk6jve9fntibh4vh6fr45k%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full');

if ($feed = $api->parse()) {
  $feed->inspect();
}
$dateList = array();
?>
<ol>
  <?php if ($feed = coreylib('https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/60vebk6jve9fntibh4vh6fr45k%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full')) { ?>
    <?php foreach($feed->get('entry') as $entry) { ?>
      <li><?php echo $entry->get('when@startTime') ?>
<?php
// this is the tricky part.  I can't save this event to an array item.
$dateList[] = $entry->get('when@startTime');
?>
</li>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</ol>
<br /><br />
<?php
print_r($dateList);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
int array_push ( $dateList , $variable_having_value_to_be_pushed )
```

array_push() treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array. The length of array increases by the number of variables pushed.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: I don't think that is the problem.  According to the document that you linked "array_push() treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array. The length of array increases by the number of variables pushed. Has the same effect as:" $array[] = $var;  I also get "502 Bad Gateway" as a result.